# Ballerina DEPLOYING ON DOCKER Sample

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I'm trying to run the "DEPLOYING ON DOCKER" sample in [this](https://ballerina.io/learn/quick-tour/).

Q1) When I call the service deployed on docker, it gives me a 500.

The logs in docker says `error: wso2.twitter:TwitterError, message: bad Authentication data.`

It seems the `twitter.toml` is not inside the docker container. That makes sense because I never mentioned in below commands that such a file is there while building the docker image.

```
$ ballerina build hello_service.bal
$ docker run -d -p 9090:9090 registry.hub.docker.com/helloworld:v1.0
$ curl -d "Hello Ballerina" -X POST localhost:9090
```

How can I provide the config file?

Q2) What's the use of `registry` here?

```
// Docker configurations
@docker:Config {
    registry:"registry.hub.docker.com",
    name:"helloworld",
    tag:"v1.0"
}
```

Comment: Q1 is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134123/deploying-the-ballerina-integration-example-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate an answer for Q2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following annotation should be added to the ballerina service. This copy the ballerina file to Docker container. Stating isBallerinaConf:true will pass the toml file to ballerina run command.

```
@docker:CopyFiles {
    files: [{source: "./twitter.toml", target: "/opt/twitter.toml", isBallerinaConf: true}]
}
```

The registry is used to push an image to a remote docker registry.

Refer sample3 for usage. The final docker image would be:

```
registry.hub.docker.com/helloworld:v.1.0
```

https://github.com/ballerinax/docker/tree/master/samples/sample3

Comment: So I hope if I'm not planning to push my image to a remote registry, I can avoid setting this value.

Comment: Yes. The registry is an optional annotation. 
Also, the image is pushed only if "push:true" attribute is set.
See https://github.com/ballerinax/docker#supported-annotations for a list of annotations and default values

Answer (score 1):

For ballerina 1.0.4 its

```
@docker:CopyFiles {
    files: [{sourceFile: "./ballerina.conf", target: "/opt/ballerina.conf", isBallerinaConf: true}]
}
```

according to
https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/docker/records/FileConfig.html